# How do I show the theorem body in thmtools \listoftheorems

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, theorems, thmtools

I would like to add a list of theorems to my document so I have included `thmtools`. This gives a list of theorems but in the following format.

> 1.1 Theorem **. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .** 24
>
> 1.2 Theorem **. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .** 25
>
> 1.3 Theorem **. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .** 28

I'd like to instead have it look something like this:

> **Theorem 1.1.** For a right angle triangle, $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ **. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .** 24
>
> **Theorem 1.2.** $\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$  **. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .** 25
>
> **Theorem 1.3.** Some other theorem **. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .** 28

I have worked out the following:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ll@theorem{%
  {\bf \thmt@thmname~ \protect\numberline{\thetheorem.~}} %
  Theorem Body goes here...
}
\def\l@thmt@theorem{} 
\makeatother
```

Which gives me this:

> **Theorem 1.1.** Theorem Body goes here... **. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .**  24
>
> **Theorem 1.2.** Theorem Body goes here... **. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .**  25
>
> **Theorem 1.3.** Theorem Body goes here... **. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .**  28

I'm just struggling to work out how to replace `Theorem Body goes here...` with the `TeX` between `\begin{theorem}` and `\end{theorem}`

And here is an example compilable document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]




\makeatletter
\def\ll@theorem{%
  {\bf \thmt@thmname~ \protect\numberline{\thetheorem.~}} %
  Theorem Body goes here...
}
\def\l@thmt@theorem{} 
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\listoftheorems


\section{Section A}

\begin{theorem}
For a right angle triangle, $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Proof...
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
$\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Proof...
\end{proof}

\section{Section B}

\begin{theorem}
Some other theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Proof...
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

Cheers

Anthony

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a working, compilable document, not only fragments

Comment: Hi, I have added a full document - let me know if anything further is required? Cheers

Comment: (not related) why **Theorem1.1**, **Theorem1.2** ? **1.1**, **1.2** isn't suffisant? since all are theorems.

Comment: I am thinking of including corollaries too, but thought I'd work how to do it with just theorems first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grabbing the `theorem` 'BODY', i.e. the content between `\begin{theorem}...\end{theorem}` can be done with `\RenewEnviron` and the `\BODY` command.

The `\RenewEnviron` command defines `theorem` to be a wrapper around the original version (which has been stored before into `\let\theorem@@orig` and `\let\theorem@@origend` command).

The package `environ` provides the `\BODY` command that contains anything between `\begin{foo}...\end{foo}` if `foo` is an environment made up with `NewEnviron` or `\RenewEnviron`.

This `\BODY` command can be used in `\ll@theorem` then!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\usepackage{environ}


\makeatletter
\def\ll@theorem{%
  {\bfseries \thmt@thmname~ \protect\numberline{\thetheorem.~}} %
  \BODY% 
}
\def\l@thmt@theorem{} 
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\let\theorem@@orig\theorem
\let\theorem@@origend\endtheorem
\RenewEnviron{theorem}{%
  \theorem@@orig%
  \BODY%
}[\theorem@@origend]
\makeatother


\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\listoftheorems


\section{Section A}

\begin{theorem}
For a right angle triangle, $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Proof...
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
  $\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
  Proof...
\end{proof}

\section{Section B}

\begin{theorem}
Some other theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Proof...
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a great solution :)

Just a slight addition, I noticed that the Theorem Body wasn't appearing in the tex (using Thesis class). It was just showing

""**Theorem 2.1.**
_Proof_. Proof....""


To fix this add `\BODY` to the RenewEnviron command:

`\RenewEnviron{theorem}{
  \theorem@@orig
  \BODY
}[\theorem@@origend]`

Comment: @Anthony: Thanks for notifying me -- I posted a different version -- the screenshot had the `\BODY` however.