# Is it possible to create table of contents with theorem numbers instead of section numbers?

Tags: table-of-contents

The title pretty much explains the question. I don't have any section in the document. Just have few theorems, so I want to create a table of contents with the section numbers and names replaced by theorem numbers and names (I have named theorems in the document). So that the page numbers are also displayed such that the names in the toc are the links to theorems. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: How do you currently add your theorems to your document? Which documentclass do you use? It seems liike you are actually interested in a list of theorems rather than a table of contents.

Comment: @leandriis, I am adding theorems using the `\begin{theorem}` and `\end{theorem}` commands. I've added `amsthm` too into the document. I am using `\documentclass{article}`.

Comment: You may call it a list of theorems, but I want it to be like table of contents (i.e. with page number displayed and where each name is the link to the theorem).

Comment: You should take a look at the `thmtools` documentation, §1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\listoftheorems` command available when adding the `thmtools` package in combination with `hyperref` for the hyperlinks should give you the desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools} % for the listoftheorems command

\usepackage{hyperref} % for the hyperlinks in the list of theorems

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\listoftheorems

\begin{theorem}
  theorem contents
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way to change what is printed instead of `Theorem` in the name of the list of theorems?

Comment: What do you want instead?

Comment: For example, let us say that we want to have `Theorem 1` `Theorem 2` etc. in the place of `Theorem` `Theorem` etc.

Comment: Or is there any way to choose custom names just to printed in list of theorems?

Comment: But aren't the theorems already numbered in the list of theorems? Why add another number to them? Regarding "custom names" how is the reader supposed to identify teh corresponding theorem in the document if their names don't match?

Comment: Probably `\begin{theorem}[theorem name]` does something closer to what you want?

Comment: The point is, let us say we want to use other proclamations (questions, say). Then the list of theorems will contain 30-40  times `1          Question` `2          Question` `3                 Question` etc. That doesn't look ok. It would be better to have `Question 1` `Question 2` etc. Or maybe there is some way to remove the name (Question, say)? Also, it would be nicer to have the name of other proclamation as heading instead of `List of theorems` always, even if the list is of `List of questions`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316324/134144 might be interesting.

Comment: Yes, it was interesting. But is there any way to change the heading to `List of Questions`?

Comment: You can use the `title` option of `\listoftheorems`: `\listoftheorems[title={List of Questions}]`

Comment: Thank you very much!